# Moving Contents of One Domain to another Domain

Tags: php

How to copy The contents of one domain to another domain using php
I used this command

if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, $movePathCMD)))
 {

```
                die("fail: unable to execute command");
            } else {

                // collect returning data from command

                  stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $data = "";
                while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) {
                    $data .= $buf;
                }
                fclose($stream);
            }
```

?>
But its not woking. Can you please Correct this code for me.

Comment: Why is it not working ? What is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
stream_get_contents($stream);
```

instead of your `while` ?